# How to change the developer's email address in 'Google hasn't verified this app' warning screen when running Google App script in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

When somebody runs the GAS script I wrote inside a Google Sheet file, they encountered the following 2 warnings:

[image]

[image]

My email address is displayed. I want to change this email address but I don't know how to. I already changed the ownership of both the GSheet and the Script to a new email address, but my old email address still shows up in the above warning screen. I also went to https://console.developers.google.com/ but I don't see any projects there.

I know that the person who runs the script can just click on Continue and Go to ... Script (Unsafe). I also know that I can just publish my macro to get it verified. But that is not the problem I am trying to solve. I want to simply change the email address displayed here.

I hope this post fits the rules of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.
Even though I didn't post any source code, it's related to software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development of Google App Script and GSheet Macros.

Comment: You have to create a standard cloud platform project, set the Oauth consent screen with the email address that you want to show and link it to the Apps Script project.

Comment: You cannot find any project because your apps script is using a default project. See more about [Default Cloud projects and Standard Cloud projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects)

Comment: Thanks guys! I followed ur tips and added my script to a cloud platform project.